# what is the solution for error Mysql shutdown unexpectedly in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

```
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2018-08-30 13:49:07 4332 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I had tried to delete the to `delete ib_logfile`'s and `ibdata1` file. after restart still not working.

Comment: Well, if you deleted the data the mysql server has little options to continue working, I would say... You will need to restore the files from your backup.

Comment: after I deleted the file and tried to run it will still generate a new file but the mysql still not running.